# If I have a diagonalized matrix with degenerate eigenvalues, how do I generate an orthonormal set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, gram-schmidt

I have the matrix

$$I = ma^2\begin{bmatrix} 4 & -1 & -1\\ -1 & 4 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda _{1,2,3} = (5ma^2,5ma^2,2ma^2)$.

I need to generate an orthonormal set of vectors from the degenerate eigenvalues.

I looked up a way to do it but I don't understand it. The Gram-Schmidt procedure takes input vectors $v_i$ and outputs an orthonormal set of vectors $u_i$. The process can be summarized as follows:

1. $u_1 = v_1$
2. $u_2 = v_2 - $(projection of $v_2$ onto $v_1$)
3. $u_3 = v_3 - $(projection of $v_3$ onto $v_2$) $-$(projection of $v_3$ onto $v_1$)

Then we simply normalize the $u_i$ vectors. But what do I use for $v_1, v_2, $and $v_3$?

Comment: I don't think that $M$ has degenerate eigenvalues... are you sure that $M$ is right?

Comment: question if you $v_i$ is orthogonal to $v_k$ for all $k\neq i$ then what are the projections going to equal as in $proj_{v_i}(v_k)=?$

Comment: @Sentinel135 If they are all orthogonal to each other then the projections would be zero.

Comment: @the_candyman I checked with Mathematica, here is the output: http://imgur.com/a/j7uU6

Comment: ok then what about the set $<5ma^2,0,0>$, $<0,5ma^2,0>$, and $<0,0,5ma^2>$; are these orthogonal?

Comment: I think you are confused about the concept of "degenerate eigenvalues"... Mathematic is saying that you have one eigenvalue ($5ma^2$) with algebraic multiplicity equal to $3$ and geometric multiplicity equal to $3$...

Comment: @the_candyman then what would be an example of degernate eigenvalues? I thought it meant when you solve for all of your eigenvalues and two or more of them turn out to be the same. In this case, all 3 of them are the same.

Comment: @Sentinel135 I would say yes. Then I think I'm confused.

Comment: @Sentinel135 a bit of background info: the goal here was to find the inertia tensor for a set of 4 mass points located on the vertices of a cube. Then I needed to find the principal moments and finally the principal axes. I found my inertia tensor to be $I= ma^2 {{4,-1,-1},{-1,4,-1},{-1,-1,4}}$. I diagonalized it to the form shown in the question. If successful, the values along the diagonal are my principal moments. Then the principal axes are the $x,y,z$ axes.

Comment: Ok what is the characteristic polynomial of, $$\begin{pmatrix}4&-1&-1\\-1&4&-1\\-1&-1&4\end{pmatrix}$$ and what are it's Eigenvalues and vectors? Hint: It's not the same as what you have above.

Comment: @Sentinel135 ah yes. My mistake. I will edit.

Comment: Are the eigenvectors: $\langle -1,0,1 \rangle, \langle -1,1,0 \rangle, \langle 1,1,1 \rangle$ ?

Comment: yes with eigenvalues $5ma^2$, $5ma^2$, and $2ma^2$ respectively.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Those are a set of eigenvalues, but they’re not an orthonormal set as the question requires.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Oops. I meant eigen*vectors*.

Comment: I knew what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use the generic procedure for finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this problem. Since this is a real symmetric matrix, you’ll end up with a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and can then apply the Gram-Schmidt process to this set to produce an orthonormal set. The latter incrementally builds an orthonormal set out of the given vectors by throwing away the components of each successive vector that are in the directions of the orthonormal vectors generated up to that point (that’s what the projections onto the other vectors are). Because of the special form of your matrix, however, we can avoid all this.

Ignoring the constant factor of $ma^2$ for the moment, since its only effect will be to scale all of the eigenvalues of the matrix, observe that we can decompose your matrix into $5I-B$, where $B$ is the $3\times3$ matrix that consists entirely of $1$s. If $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $(5I-B)\mathbf v=(5-\lambda)\mathbf v$, so $\mathbf v$ is also an eigenvector of your matrix with eigenvalue $5-\lambda$. $B$ has rank one, so has zero as a double eigenvalue, and the trace of $B$ tells us that the remaining eigenvalue is $3$, so the eigenvalues of your matrix are $5$, $5$ and $2$.

We can find eigenvectors by computing kernels of various singular matrices derived from the eigenvalues as usual, but can also take a short cut here. The row sums of $B$ (and of your matrix) are identical, but summing over the rows is the same as right-multiplying by $(1,1,1)^T$, so that’s an eigenvector, and it corresponds to the eigenvalue $5-3=2$. We know that a real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so the eigenspace of $5$ is two-dimensional. In addition, eigenspaces of different eigenvalues of such a matrix are orthogonal, which means that we can take any linearly independent pair of vectors orthogonal to $(1,1,1)^T$ as our eigenvectors of $5$. To avoid having to go through the Gram-Schmidt process, we take advantage of the fact that we’re working in $\mathbb R^3$. First, we pick some vector that’s orthogonal to $(1,1,1)^T$ by inspection: $(1,-1,0)^T$ is an obvious choice. Now we want a vector that’s orthogonal to them both, so we compute the cross product $(1,1,1)^T\times(1,-1,0)^T=(1,1,-2)^T$. You can verify that these are indeed eigenvectors of $5$. All that’s left to do is normalize these three vectors. Physically, the fact that we can choose any two vectors orthogonal to the principal axis $(1,1,1)^T$ as our other principal axes reflects the symmetry of the masses about this axis.

Comment: Wait, so the eigenvectors of my matrix $I$ are ***not*** my principal axes? For the eigenvectors I got  ⟨−1,0,1⟩,⟨−1,1,0⟩,⟨1,1,1⟩

Comment: @loltospoon They are, but the axes are not unique because of the symmetry about the third axis (what are the principal axes of a uniform sphere?): $\langle0,1,-1\rangle$ is also an eigenvector of 5, so you could take that and either of the other two vectors that you have for the basis of that eigenspace instead. Note, however, that you’re not quite done: the first two vectors do span the eigenspace of 5, but they’re not orthogonal, and none of the three is a unit vector.

Comment: amd's right what $<-1,0,1>$, $<-1,1,0>$ and $<1,1,1>$ are the set of $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$. Now you need to find the orthogonal relationship to those three vectors. For that you need to use the Grand-Schmitt procedure you mentioned. Sorry for the mistake.